# TypeScript - Property 'xyz' is declared but never used

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have been reading about this error on Stackoverflow and there are **many** posts related to it however I cant seem to find a solution to it or maybe I am just not able to understand it.

Taking the following 4 imports and constructor as an example I will try to explain what is happening.

```
    import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage"; // I am using this
    import { Common } from "../providers/common"; // I am **not** using this
    import { CacheService } from "ionic-cache"; // I am using this
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http"; // I am using this

      constructor( 
        public http: HttpClient, 
        public storage: Storage, 
        public cmn: Common, 
        public cache: CacheService ) {
          console.log("Hello Service Provider");
      }
```

I will share the usage of each below but before I want to mention out of all 4 arguments in constructor I am only getting the warning on 2.

```
import { CacheService } from "ionic-cache";
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
```

There are no warning for import `HttpClient`, good but I have no idea why because I am accessing it just like I am accessing others.

Strangest of all is import `Common` because I am actually not using `Common` anywhere intentionally and as far as my understanding goes I should only be getting the warning for `Common`

Usage of `HttpClient` and `CacheService`

```
  //Get the list of industries
  getIndustries(refresher?): Observable<any> {
    let cacheKey = "industries";
    // delayType if set to all, will ping server everything, if it is set to none then only on expiry of data api call will be sent
    let delayType = refresher ? "all" : "none";

    let request = this.http
    .get(`${this.URL}industries`)
    .map((response: Response) => response)
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
    return this.cache.loadFromDelayedObservable( cacheKey, request, "", 60, delayType );
  }
```

**Question 1**

In above example you can see I am using `this.http` and `this.cache`, yet I only see a warning for cache but not the http, please help me understand why this is.

Similarly I am also making use of storage as following in another function

```
let server = this.storage.get("url");
```

And yet I see another warning on Storage imports being unused.

**Question 2**

Why am I not getting a warning for `import { Common } from "../providers/common";` I am literally not using this anywhere.

I know I can suppress these warnings to ignore them but I really do not want to as I rather understand the cause of this.

I will really appreciate any help on this.

If it is of any help, I am using

```
Typescript 2.5.1
Angular 5
Ionic 3.9.2
```

Comment: You are using `Common` in the constructor args: `public cmn: Common`

Comment: @H.B. Could you please elaborate? I am using others as arguments as well why are they giving warnings then?

Comment: Can you clarify what exact warnings you get? Are they about the imports or about the arguments in the constructor? Because using a type that was imported should be enough to not get any warnings on the import itself.

Comment: Also, why not upgrade Typescript?

Comment: @H.B. The warning is about import.

Comment: There is no reason to not upgrade will probably do.